# PNG figures in black and white

Tags: graphics, pdf, png, dvips, ps

I'm trying to include a png figure and it works when I see it in dvi, but the ps comes in black and white.

If I compile directly to pdf there is no problem. However I'm using psTricks for a different figure, so I need to use ps first.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try using `dvips -I c <filename>` instead of just `dvips <filename>` (see http://www.win.tue.nl/latex/faq.html#q16).

Answer (score 11):

You have to convert your DVI file to PS using `dvips -I c <filename>` instead of just `dvips <filename>` (http://www.win.tue.nl/latex/faq.html#q16). The `-I` switch is used to select image options, the `c` stands for color, grayscale would be `g` (http://docs.miktex.org/manual/dvips.html).