# Color Image to Grayscale conversion by using dvips in MikTeX

Tags: color, dvips

I found an answer that how to convert the color images into Gray(B/W) scale, refer the below link:

[PNG figures in black and white](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125576/png-figures-in-black-and-white)

But if I follow the suggestion, i.e., dvips -I g , then some error "dvips: ! Invalid option `-I'. Try --help for more information. " is coming, please suggest what went wrong with my tag and my tags are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centerline{\includegraphics{Color.eps}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right, this option does not exist (anymore). Are you fixed to dvips?

Comment: Yes, I should meet the requirement by using "dvips" and my general requirement is TeX->DVI->dvips ->ps2pdf or generate PDF through Acrobat Distiller

Comment: Using TeX on a LaTeX document? How do you do that? Do you use any packages that prevent you from using pdf(la)tex? Because else you would have the option of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/150219/124577) answer. I don't know whether this works with dvi.

Comment: When you use `ps2pdf`, try including the options `-sColorConversionStrategy=Gray -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceGray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the answer to fix my requirement, refer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/E2EtYQC-A0Y/RoLCFm_5CAAJ special thanks to Herbert...And the answer given below:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\setGray{\special{ps:
    true setglobal globaldict begin
    /setrgbcolor { 0.07 mul exch 0.71 mul add exch 0.21 mul add setgray
} def
    end false setglobal
}}
\AtBeginDocument{\setGray}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\setGray
\centerline{\includegraphics{colorrgbmake2.eps}}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

\begin{figure}
\setGray
\centerline{\includegraphics{colorrgbmake2.eps}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```